# Azure cosmos DB Emulator change port

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb

I am new to Azure Cosmos DB. The cosmos DB emulator which is running on port 8084 "https://localhost:8084/_explorer/index.html". When I tried to get Cosmos DB Context information through PowerShell, it says that Cosmos DB BaseUri port is 8081 "https://localhost:8081/". How to change the BaseUri port.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change the port by starting the emulator from the command line.

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /Port=<port>
```

There's a whole range of command line options you can use. You can refer to all of these here.

[Manage the emulator with command-line syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator-command-line-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by replacing the localhost values to a different port for EMULATOR_ENDPOINT in the: [Cosmos DB files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Y8h.png)

Once that was done, Cosmos DB launched with the new port and I was able to write data to the new URI